# Defer img loading until after pageload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm wondering if there is any standard to defer all  loads, and then programatically call them later? Interested in doing something like Facebook, wherein extremely small blurry jpegs are set as background-image, and then the full res images are called in on pageload.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<img class='load-later' src='example.com/image.jpg'>
```

**CSS**

```
img.load-later {
    background-image: url('blurry-preview.jpg');
}
```

**JS**

```
function pageLoad() {
    $('.load-later').load();
}
```

Comment: That's called progressive loading http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/574/progressive-jpeg-why-do-many-web-sites-avoid-rendering-jpegs-that-way-pros  If you now want to lazy load images instead, then there are many plugins already available, e.g:  http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload  But now, i'm not sure what is your question?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the src property to the "blurry-preview.jpg" image at first, and then change it to the actual image src at a later stage. Stupid-simple example (using JQuery):

```
<img src="blurry-preview.jpg" alt="something" class="imgo" />

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.imgo').attr('src', 'goodlooking-image.jpg');
 });
```

This makes more sense if you for example use img tags with data-[x] attributes holding the src (or other attributes) you wish to apply later on. Here is an example that modifies "srcset" and "size" instead of src:

```
<img src="blurry-preview.jpg" alt="something" class="imgo" data-srcset="m.jpg 300w, l.jpg 600w" data-sizes="(max-width: 500px) 100vw, (max-width: 1000px) 33vw, 600px" />
```

Javascript altering image tag using data from it's data-[x] attributes (modifying srcset/sizes rather than src, as per your request):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.imgo').each(function () {
        $this = $(this)
        $this.attr('srcset', $this.data('srcset'));
        $this.attr('sizes', $this.data('sizes'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Any way to make this compatible with srcset?

Comment: @JohnDoe Use instead other attribute than `src` which when parsed will make the image to be loaded. E., use `data-src` and on page load `$(window).on('load', function(){$('img[data-src]').each(function(){this.src= this.dataset.src;});});`

Comment: @John Doe, Yes, you can manipulate srcset and sizes attributes of the images after load has completed if you want to. Tested in Chrome, it seems to apply those attributes even if they are dynamically added, e.g. in JQuery $(document).ready(...), and not initially present.

Comment: @Culme If you want to update your answer with the data-src method, I'll award the answer to you

Answer (score 1):

You could load the images on document ready. With the something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// set images here
});
```

You would need to update the src attributes of your images inside the document ready function.